# Hive is taking long time for limit 1 queries

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive

I have recently setup Hive. I have created an external table to access the database present in MongoDB. Now, if I run a query like `SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 1;` it will take about an average of 18 seconds to execute the command. It will take the same amount of time even if the `LIMIT` is set to 10, 100, 1000, 10000. The log contains something like this :

```
2015-08-24 09:19:37,918 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-29]: splitter.MongoCollectionSplitter (MongoCollectionSplitter.java:createSplitFromBounds(163)) - Created split: min=null, max= { "_id" : { "$oid" : "55cdbffaa9ad1735c531a362"}}
2015-08-24 09:19:37,918 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-29]: splitter.MongoCollectionSplitter (MongoCollectionSplitter.java:createSplitFromBounds(163)) - Created split: min={ "_id" : { "$oid" : "55cdbffaa9ad1735c531a362"}}, max= { "_id" : { "$oid" : "55cdc000a9ad1735d5cb42ab"}}
2015-08-24 09:19:37,918 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-29]: splitter.MongoCollectionSplitter (MongoCollectionSplitter.java:createSplitFromBounds(163)) - Created split: min={ "_id" : { "$oid" : "55cdc000a9ad1735d5cb42ab"}}, max= { "_id" : { "$oid" : "55cdc002a9ad1735d5cb56f9"}}
2015-08-24 09:19:37,918 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-29]: splitter.MongoCollectionSplitter (MongoCollectionSplitter.java:createSplitFromBounds(163)) - Created split: min={ "_id" : { "$oid" : "55cdc002a9ad1735d5cb56f9"}}, max= { "_id" : { "$oid" : "55cdc008a9ad1735eaffb513"}}
2015-08-24 09:19:37,919 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-29]: splitter.MongoCollectionSplitter (MongoCollectionSplitter.java:createSplitFromBounds(163)) - Created split: min={ "_id" : { "$oid" : "55cdc008a9ad1735eaffb513"}}, max= { "_id" : { "$oid" : "55cdc00ba9ad1735eaffc961"}}
2015-08-24 09:19:37,919 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-29]: splitter.MongoCollectionSplitter (MongoCollectionSplitter.java:createSplitFromBounds(163)) - Created split: min={ "_id" : { "$oid" : "55cdc00ba9ad1735eaffc961"}}, max= { "_id" : { "$oid" : "55cdc012a9ad1735fab2a0dd"}}
2015-08-24 09:19:37,919 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-29]: splitter.MongoCollectionSplitter (MongoCollectionSplitter.java:createSplitFromBounds(163)) - Created split: min={ "_id" : { "$oid" : "55cdc012a9ad1735fab2a0dd"}}, max= null
```

Actually there are many similar rows in between, I omitted them. From the log I can only guess that even when I do `limit 1` Hive gets the entire collection from MongoDB and then selects 1 to display. Is there any way to change this so Hive only gets 1 row when I do `limit 1`?

Answer (score 0):

In case of Hive tables (probably true for external table also) if you SELECT just a specific field from the DB with LIMIT a Map Reduce task (or whatever execution engine you're using) started, while if you SELECT * that doesn't require Map Reduce -> it's much faster. This could be the reason of the slowness.